# Removing any zeros from the end of an integer

Tags: ruby, integer, trim

I would like to remove any zeros from the end of an integer. For example, if I have `14260`, I would like to end up with `1426`. `142600` I would also like to end up with `1426`.

I have had a look around and can't find a solution for integers, just a lot of people talking about removing leading zeros and zeros from floats.

Answer (score 6):

convert to string, sub and convert back to int:

```
142600.to_s.sub(/0+$/,'') # /0+$/ is regex to find all trailing 0s
#=> "1426"

14200006000000000.to_s.sub(/0+$/,'').to_i
#=> 14200006
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.

May I ask what the significance of the +$ is? Should I need to remove a different character from a string, would I be able to replace the 0 in that sequence with my desired character for removal?

Comment: `/0+$/` means you are looking for consecutive `0`s at the end of the string. Yes you can replace `0` with any desired character, it will look for that consecutive character at the end of string.

Answer (score 3):

To additional, you can process it like number:

```
num = 1220000
num_without_zeros = num

while num_without_zeros % 10 == 0 do
  num_without_zeros /= 10
end

num_without_zeros
#=> 122
```

Comment: though correct, one disadvantage is you are losing original int.

Comment: @shivam, i think it does not matter in this particular instance, but anyway, i've updated my answer, thank you:)

Comment: its true it may not matter for OP, but its always better to preserve values if not desired otherwise :)

Comment: The question can be avoided by expressing the algorithm as a method.